# Minimum of sum of squares over sums

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, closed-form

I am trying to minimize $\phi(\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^K$.

$\phi(\alpha) = \frac{R^2 + G^2 \gamma \sum_{i=0}^{K} A_i \alpha_i^2}{\sum_{i=0}^{K} A_i \alpha_i} $

Where, $A_i = \gamma \beta^i (K+1-i)$. $K, \beta, \gamma$  are constants. $K$ is a positive integer, $\beta \in (0,1)$, $\gamma = 1 - \beta$.

I am trying to obtain a sequence $\alpha_i$ which will minimize $\phi(\alpha)$. I am proceeding the standard way of differentiating $\phi(\alpha)$ with respect to each $\alpha_i$ and setting it to zero. Further, I know $\phi(\alpha)$ is a convex function. My final objective is to obtain a solution in closed form, however it is turning out to be a nightmare.

I am actually solving a generalization of a problem. The special case being when $A_i$ are constants. In which case it is easy to argue that $\phi(\alpha)$ is a symmetric convex function and the solution should the one in which $\alpha_i$ are constants.

Am I proceeding in the correct direction? Please suggest.

Comment: I see no reason to believe you will be able to get a closed form solution. Learn to be content with a numerical solution!

Comment: I cannot really do this with CVX. Can pointers on reducing this problem to another one which I can attempt to solve with CVX?

Comment: I'm not suggesting CVX, rather a gradient or Newton method.

Comment: Anyway, I figured out I can do this with CVX much faster using the epigraph/bisection trick.

Comment: No, go back to your CVX Forum question. This can be solved directly in CVX, no bisection needed. I still say CVX is overkill here.

Answer (score -1):

I seeked a numerical solution to this problem. This problem being a {convex}./{linear} cannot be directly solved with CVX for example. Epi-graph trick and bisection give a way to solve this problem numerically.

Thus this problem can be transformed to,

$\underset{\alpha_0,\cdots,\alpha_K}{ minimize }\ t \\
 subject\ to\ \ \ numerator \leq t \times denominator $

Which in turn can be solved by bi-section. Here is the code with matlab/CVX. Repeat this code with various t, which can be initially chosen as average of an upper bound and an lower bound and updating the upper bound or lower bound based on if the problem is feasible or not.

```
cvx_begin 
variable alphaS(K)
minimize 1
subject to
( R^2 + G^2 * sum_square( diag(b) * alphaS ) ) - t * (2*sum(alphaS) ) <= 0
alphaS >= 0
cvx_end
```

Entire matlab script,

```
b = zeros(K,1);
for p=1:K
    b(p) = 1-beta^p;
end

maxSubDivisions = 20;

% epigraph trick / bisection
upper = 2;
lower = 0;

loopCount=0;
while( 1 )
    loopCount = loopCount + 1;

    t=(upper+lower)/2;
    cvx_begin quiet
    variable alphaS(K)
    minimize 1
    subject to
    ( R^2 + G^2 * sum_square( diag(b) * alphaS ) ) - t * (2*sum(alphaS) ) <= 0
    alphaS >= 0
    cvx_end

    display( sprintf( '#%d : %s', loopCount, cvx_status ) );
    if( strcmp( cvx_status, 'Infeasible' ) == 1 )
        lower = t;
    end


    if( strcmp( cvx_status, 'Failed' ) == 1 )
        break;
    end

    len = length(strfind( cvx_status, 'Solved' ));
    if( ( len == 1) )
        upper = t;
        optArg = alphaS;
        optFVal = t;


        if( length(strfind( cvx_status, 'Inaccurate' )) == 1 )
            break;
        end
        if( loopCount > maxSubDivisions )
            break;
        end

    end


end
```

Comment: Hmm, you must have missed the answers over on the CVX Forum, because in fact this problem *can* be solved directly in CVX.

Comment: Ohh yes, I missed your answer in CVX forum. So I understand if solving with CVX I can use `quad_over_lin()'. I guess I needed an immediate answer to the optimization thus I used CVX, I understand solving this problem with CVX can be an overkill.